# Is it possible to send the FCM notifications for 2 different apps with different firebase projects using cloud functions

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implement FCM push notifications using cloud functions for android and IOS . I am receiving notification to my app with same firebase project.. Now I need to send the notifications to other other with other firebase project.

suppose APP A sends the device token  to APP B (ServerB as cloud functions). Server B takes the device token and sent the notification to APP A using Cloud Functions. But in  Firebase logs it shows notification has been sent . But App A is not receiving  the notification. I have seen many posts but I did not get to implementation.

Comment: the device token generated is different for different app, so here you have to send individually notification to two different user, then it will receive on the receiver side.

Comment: upove comment is correct,the only solution i think of is that you need to configure the app to multiple firebase project so you can store the different token in the database,,,https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/

Answer (score 0):

Here the device token generated is different for different firebase project, so in database you have to save two device token for different firebase project.

Now suppose user have to send notification from **App A** to **App B** then device token of user of **APP B** should be used to send notification, then it will receive on the receiver side.

> **Imp Note**:-
>
> when you send notification to a particular app let say **APP A**, then you should have to use server key of **APP A** firebase project.

Comment: I am getting the device  token  of App B  using api  to the cloud functions and executing the notification . It shows Successfully sent but appb not receiving any notification

Comment: @vijju, please check on your side properly, when device token is right then it will always show successfully sent in console, but the receiver side should be login and having that device token on which you are sending.

Comment: I have loged in the app and the refresh token I have used . And also I checked in the firebase console too. I shows a failed notification

Comment: @vijju, if it shows failed in console, then please check the server key which you use.

Comment: I am using the APP A firebase server key to send notifications to APP B device token. Did you get what my question is ?

Comment: @vijju, please try the same above with **appB** server key, and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177335/discussion-between-vijju-and-nirav-bhavsar).